# Trigger my Jenkins build job using cURL commands

Tags: curl, jenkins, triggers, unauthorized

I wanted to trigger my jenkins build using cURL.exe, i tried with the following command:

```
curl -k -X POST -u username:APItoken https://Jenkins_URL/view/All/job/JobName/build
```

But I am facing the issue as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"
<html><head>
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
</body></html>
```

(Other cURL commands like GET and POST works fine, only this cURL command shows this issue).
I have checked with several sites, and all places the same command is mentioned. kindly provide some inputs if someone had used it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The above issue got resolved when i tried giving proper API token. Because in my scenario, there are 2 Jenkins A and B. By mistake i have provided API token of Jenkins A while trying to execute build job which is present in Jenkins B.

That is the reason why i faced the "Unauthorized" issue.